# Close Jira issue via Git commit

Tags: git, commit, jira

Does anyone know if it's possible to change the status of a Jira issue using a Git commit?
I am using Jira and Git with the Jira Git plugin and I know I can reference an issue by just adding the name in the commit but I thought a commit message like "ISSUE-1 #close" would set the status to closed. But this doesn't seem to work.

Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to send commands via the commit message?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you have FishEye installed you can [use smart commits](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/FISHEYE/Using+Smart+Commits) to trigger various actions from a single commit.

Comment: But can you use smart commits with Atlassian stash git repos? From what I read you can't

Comment: That's correct.  You need fisheye to enable smart commits.  Please vote on https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/STASH-2490.  It carries already 266 votes, hopefully atlassian will listen.

Answer (score 7):

Here is what you need to do to enable 'smart commits':

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Enabling+DVCS+smart+commits

Then, the syntax to use in the commit messages:

```
<ISSUE_KEY> #<CMD> <optional CMD_PARAMETERS>
```

Example:

```
JRA-123 #resolve
```

More info on the syntax here:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AOD/Processing+JIRA+issues+with+commit+messages

Comment: But this only works for cloud versions of Jira, right?

Comment: Well, Atlassian documents mention 'Jira Software'. So I am sure it should work with both In-premise and cloud versions of Jira.